# How to send real time sensor data from the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 to the Galaxy Gear?

Tags: android, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have connected a Wireless sensor network to the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 via an OTG cable and I am tracking the real time sensor data on the phone.

Will it be possible to see this data on the Galaxy Gear? What should I do to see this data on the Gear?

I tried opening a Bluetooth socket connection using Eclipse but I am not successful in sending/receiving data. Is this the right approach or should I use the Samsung SDK for this?

Comment: This is a little vague... Have you written any code yet, or are you just trying to find out if it's possible?

Comment: I have developed an app on the phone which displays the real time sensor data, I want to now see this data on the gear.Initially for testing purposes,I tried to open a Bluetooth socket connection between 2 android phones and just developed a sample application to send data from 1 phone to another and it worked fine. When I tried to do the same with the phone and gear, it does not work. The App on the gear crashes in few seconds after being deployed so I wonder if it is actually possible to send data from the phone to the watch and if it is possible,is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: how frequently u send data?